# Move HTML element before other in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I wokring in magento enviroment where js create dynamic html.Now i want to move one element before the other.As this possible because html is also loading form js and replace will be applied on that ? My final html code is displayed as :

```
<div class="x-tree-node-el folder active-category x-tree-node-collapsed" id="extdd-3"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img class="x-tree-icon" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif"></span><img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif" id="ext-gen27"><img unselectable="on" class="x-tree-node-icon" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif" id="ext-gen24"><a tabindex="1" href="#" hidefocus="on" id="ext-gen21"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-4">Laptops (2)</span></a><input type="checkbox" class="copycate" value="110" name="tree['110']"></div>
```

I want to move input typ="checkobx" before the anchor tage.Like my final result will be

```
 <div class="x-tree-node-el folder active-category x-tree-node-collapsed" id="extdd-3"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img class="x-tree-icon" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif"></span><img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif" id="ext-gen27"><img unselectable="on" class="x-tree-node-icon" src="http://extjs.com/s.gif" id="ext-gen24">
<input type="checkbox" class="copycate" value="110" name="tree['110']">
<a tabindex="1" href="#" hidefocus="on" id="ext-gen21"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-4">Laptops (2)</span></a></div>
```

I try this code but don't work.

```
 <script>
  $('.copycate').insert({
  before: "<a>",
  after: "<img>"
});
  </script>
```

Comment: I would try to answer the question but scrolling sideways sucks and I'm too lazy to edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.copycate').insertBefore($('#ext-gen21'));
```

[jQuery API - insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)